# Express server not loading CSS static files?

Tags: node.js, express

I have used middleware to load the static css files but its not working. When I simply open the html/ejs file without servers , the css is loaded. But when I use an express server to do the same , it doesn't work.

In the network section in the developer tools , it shows 404 error for the css files.

Express code:

```
//express
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const path = require('path');

app.set('view engine' , 'ejs');

//middleware
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//home route
app.get('/' , (req , res) =>{
    res.render('todosample');
});

//listning to port
app.listen(8080);
```

File structure is :

```
public
    todosamplestyle.css
views
    todosample.ejs
app.js
```

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/todosamplestyle.css">
    <title>Greatest To-do ever</title>
</head>
<body>
   <header>
       <span>Greatest To-Do Ever</span>
       <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
            </ul>
       </nav>
   </header> 
   <main>
       <form action="#">
           <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="search" id="">
           <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Item">
       </form>
   </main>
   <div class="items">
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio<button class="btn btn-outline-danger">X</button></li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in<button class="btn btn-outline-danger">X</button></li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus<button class="btn btn-outline-danger">X</button></li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac<button class="btn btn-outline-danger">X</button></li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros<button class="btn btn-outline-danger">X</button></li>

        </ul>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: change the stylesheet to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./todosamplestyle.css">` and check if it works

Comment: The public directory is served at the root so the href should be `href="/todosamplestyle.css"` I mean the `<app-folder>/public/todosamplestyle.css` is served at `http://localhost:8080/todosamplestyle.css`

Answer (score 0):

You are sharing the CSS files using `express.static` at `/`. So path of your CSS files will be: `http://host:port/todosamplestyle.css`

And you are rendering the `/` route. That means your CSS path will be `./todosamplestyle.css`

If you want to prefix your statics with `/public` you can do that by

```
app.use('/public', express.static('public'))
```